# How to have diff beetwen to tables of date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL requests. The first represents the times of entry of a person and the second exit times.

Something like this for entry :

```
2012-11-30 07:33:53
2012-11-01 07:31:44
2012-11-02 07:35:21
2012-11-19 07:25:48
2012-11-20 07:26:01
...
```

And this for exit :

```
2012-11-01 15:35:27
2012-11-02 15:48:34
2012-11-19 15:38:03
2012-11-20 15:40:25
2012-11-21 15:37:04
2012-11-22 15:35:28
...
```

I want to have the number of worked hour (entry time - exit time). I don't know how to do.

This my request :

```
SELECT Sum(CONVERT(FLOAT, event201211.dbo.evacc.edate)) AS Expr1
FROM   dbo.uclassdef
       INNER JOIN dbo.uclass
               ON dbo.uclass.mclass = dbo.uclassdef.mclass
                  AND dbo.uclass.sclass = dbo.uclassdef.sclass
       INNER JOIN dbo.cards
               ON dbo.cards.fpointeur = dbo.uclass.fpointeur
       INNER JOIN event201211.dbo.evacc
               ON dbo.cards.fpointeur = event201211.dbo.evacc.fpointeur
WHERE  ( event201211.dbo.evacc.ecd = 1 )
       AND ( dbo.cards.fpointeur = '5456' )
```

Do you have a solution?

**Edit 1**

The field are name Expr1. There is on field per request. This is date columns. I want to have hours:minutes but minutes are ok too.

Comment: how are the names of both fields?  are they of type DATE??? and which unit do you want the result (minutes, hours, hours:minutes)?

Answer (score 0):

You have some unknowns (like data types, exact output format etc). You can use this:

```
datediff(hh, Entry, Exit)
```